# update data in existing row in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, post

I have a table called pack_details with 4 columns. I'm trying to insert new data into an existing table. Can somebody tell me what's wrong with my codes and why i have a parse error?

```
$sql_query = "UPDATE pack_details SET $delivery_date = $_POST["delivery_date"], $delivery_time = $_POST["delivery_time"]
WHERE $delivery_building = $_POST["delivery_building"]
AND $delivery_room = $_POST["delivery_room"]";
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: You can not use double quotes inside double quotes without escaping it. Also, in a mySQL query you have to wrap string data by single quotes. Change in `SET $delivery_date = '{$_POST['delivery_date']}', ` etc...

Comment: Thanks @fusion3k. Now it says that i have an error in your SQL syntax at this part of my code. 'delivery_time = WHERE delivery_building = AND delivery_room ='

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any from below options:

```
 $sql_query = "UPDATE pack_details SET $delivery_date = '{$_POST['delivery_date']}', $delivery_time = '{$_POST['delivery_time']}' WHERE $delivery_building = '{$_POST['delivery_building']}' AND $delivery_room = '{$_POST['delivery_room']}'";
```

or

```
 $sql_query = "UPDATE pack_details SET delivery_date = '".$_POST["delivery_date"]."', delivery_time = '".$_POST["delivery_time"]."' WHERE delivery_building = '".$_POST["delivery_building"]."' AND delivery_room = '".$_POST["delivery_room"]."'";
```

Note: If field name doesn't contain $, remove $ from field name in query. For eg. "$delivery_date" should be "delivery_date"

Suggestion: Instead of using string concatenation for building, You should use bind parameters to pass value to query. It helps to prevent SQL injection as well as code look well.

Comment: Thanks for the advices, now it says...
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' delivery_time = WHERE delivery_building = AND delivery_room =' at line 1. what's wrong with this part of my sentence?

Comment: You must not have added quotes for string and date type field.  Which query you have tried?

Comment: $sql_query = "UPDATE pack_details SET delivery_date = $_POST[delivery_date], delivery_time = $_POST[delivery_time]
WHERE delivery_building = $_POST[delivery_building] AND delivery_room = $_POST[delivery_room]";

Comment: Try $sql_query = "UPDATE pack_details SET $delivery_date = '".$_POST["delivery_date"]."', $delivery_time = '".$_POST["delivery_time"]."' WHERE $delivery_building = '".$_POST["delivery_building"]."' AND $delivery_room = '".$_POST["delivery_room"]."'";

Comment: This should also work $sql_query = "UPDATE pack_details SET $delivery_date = '$_POST[\"delivery_date\"]', $delivery_time = '$_POST[\"delivery_time\"]' WHERE $delivery_building = '$_POST[\"delivery_building\"]' AND $delivery_room = '$_POST[\"delivery_room\"]'";

Comment: Try this: $sql_query = "UPDATE pack_details SET delivery_date = '".$_POST["delivery_date"]."', delivery_time = '".$_POST["delivery_time"]."' WHERE delivery_building = '".$_POST["delivery_building"]."' AND delivery_room = '".$_POST["delivery_room"]."'";

Comment: If you are still getting error after above query, do echo $sql_query and tell me what it prints.

Comment: Yaaaaaye this last one worked!!! Thanks Krunal.
However when i execute my App it doesn't update these above data inside  the table

Comment: echo the query and tried to execute query directly in your database. Check whether such record exists or not

Comment: @Drickuss, Your upvote would be appreciated if it worked.

Comment: how do i echo the query and tried to execute query directly in my database, please

Comment: Use "echo $sql_query;" to print your sql query. And execute built query in sql command prompt or in phpMyAdmin

Comment: i'd like to update the data only in the last row, not in the entire column